# where is ejabberd.yml in Windows?

Tags: ejabberd

I installed ejabberd in Windows. I looked it up in ejabberd documentation for a long time and checked ejabberd installation folder(C:\Program Files\ejabberd-15.09 in my computer), but didn't find the file `ejabberd.yml`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the folder, it's `C:\Users\gzc\AppData\Roaming\ejabberd\conf` in my computer. My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I searched in the official documentation but never found the right information.

Answer (score 13):

Actually I found mine in: C:\ProgramData\ejabberd\conf

Comment: I also found in the same

Answer (score 4):

In My case Windows 10 and Ejabberd-18.03 it is "C:\ProgramData\ejabberd\conf" , I hope it will help another user like me because i was finding that file on recommended location by other users like above comments.